# Selected button tag is showing properly in the console log but button background is not changing

Tags: ios

[image]I have a table cell and inside the cell there are four radio buttons.
Whenever a radio button is selected, it calls the following method : radioButtonClicked

```
- (IBAction)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1:

            if ([self.customCell.button1 isSelected] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"inside if case 1");
                [self.customCell.button1 setSelected:NO];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"inside else case 1");                
                [self.customCell.button1 setSelected:YES];
                [self.customCell.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [self.customCell.button2 setSelected:NO];
                [self.customCell.button3 setSelected:NO];
                [self.customCell.button4 setSelected:NO];
            }
            break;
 ....... same code is repeated for the rest of the radio buttons.
```

The problem is that i am getting "inside else case 1" in the console which means the correct radio button is selected in code but the background image is not changing to checked.png.

I have declared a separate class for customcell and i have referenced that class in my table.

its really puzzling why this background image is not getting selected even though the image files are placed in the images.xassets folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after calling `TouchUpInsideHandler` UIKit deselects the button.
e.g. You are setting selected in `TouchUpInsideHandler`, but UIKit deselects back.

Solution is super simple, you need to select button after short delay.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.someButton setSelected:YES];
});
```

So your code should by like this:

```
- (IBAction)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1: {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([self.customCell.button1 isSelected] == YES) {
                    NSLog(@"inside if case 1");
                    [self.customCell.button1 setSelected:NO];
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"inside else case 1");
                    [self.customCell.button1 setSelected:YES];
                    [self.customCell.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    [self.customCell.button2 setSelected:NO];
                    [self.customCell.button3 setSelected:NO];
                    [self.customCell.button4 setSelected:NO];
                }
            });
            break;
            }
            ....... same code is repeated for the rest of the radio buttons.
    }
}
```

Comment: When i add this for case 1, case 2 is complaining that : switch case is in protected scope.

Comment: @user3769888 see edited version ( I have added block in case )

Comment: Still showing the same outcome even after changing.

Comment: Can you copy paste modified code, and also full error message.

Comment: i am sorry what i meant was the button background is not changing the switch case related error is gone though. Let me try the other suggestions. thanks for the help l0gg3r.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't implement a true radio button, as it is possible to have no button selected - touching the currently selected button will turn it off and not turn any other button on.

For simpler code I would suggest adding your buttons to an NSArray (`self.buttons` in my code below). You can do this by dragging a connection from the "new referencing outlet collection" in Interface Builder.  Drag each button to the same collection property.

Then implement this method as your 'touch up inside handler'

```
- (void)setButton:(UIButton *)button selectedState:(BOOL)state {

   UIImage *image;
   if (state) {
          image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]
   }
   else {
          image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]
   }
   button.selected=state;
   [button setImage:image forState:UIControlNormal];
 }


- (IBAction)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (UIButton *b in self.buttons) {
       if (b==sender) {
          [self setButton:b selectedState:YES];
          self.selectedButton=b.tag;   
       }
       else {
          [self setButton:b selectedState:NO];
       }
    }
}
```

This code implements true radio button functionality - you can't have no selection.  If you wanted the ability to have no selection you could use this -

```
- (IBAction)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (UIButton *b in self.buttons) {
       if (b==sender) {
          if (b.selected) {
            [self setButton:b selectedState:NO];
            self.selectedButton=-1; 
          } else {
            [self setButton:b selectedState:YES];
            self.selectedButton=b.tag;   
          }
       }
       else {
          [self setButton:b selectedState:NO];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: My buttons are mapped to the customCellViewController class of UITableViewCell type. My table view is in another class, this should not create a problem right. so where do i declare the array of buttons? in the cell class or the tableview?

Comment: Is it a static content table view?  The tableview class would be the place for the array - the cell only has visibility of a single button

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood - if the 4 buttons are in the same cell, then the array will be in the cell